# Why can we do str:split(",") but not tab:insert(val)?

Tags: string, methods, lua, lua-table

We can do either `string.split("1,2,3",",")` or `("1,2,3"):split(",")` and receive the same result.

However `tab = {} table.insert(tab, "hi")` works while `tab = {} tab:insert("hi")` throws the error

> tab = {} tab:insert("hi"):1: attempt to call a nil value

This seems inconsistent, am I doing something wrong or is there a good reason why calling methods in Lua is different?

Thank you,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because strings have a default metatable in Lua, but tables do not. You can set the metatable yourself:

```
local tab = setmetatable({}, {__index = table})
tab:insert("hi")
print(#tab)
```

This should print 1. See [2.4](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#2.4) and [6.4](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#6.4) sections in the Lua Manual for details.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much!!! As a follow up, is it possible to set this to be the global behavior for all tables?

Comment: I don't think it's possible with tables (at least not without tweaking the source), but maybe others can comment on this as well.

Comment: I was experimenting a little and reading the documentation. While not sure about modifying the base table metadata, I was able to just create a new base table object who I can add additional behavior to and work as my base. Thank you!